# Add a picklist value to Global Value Set in test class

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, test-setup, pricebookentry, global-picklist

I am working on test class that inserts an Opportunity with the opportunity products using the correct price book/price book entry. The OpportunityLineItem has a ProductSelected__c picklist field. We recently implemented the Global value sets and this picklist is now using the active values from the Global value set. How do I do the following?

1) Create an opportunity (not a problem)

2) Create opportunity line items (not a problem)

3) How do I setup a new test value into the Global Value set and add the same into the ProductSelected__c picklist?

4) Apply the same ProductSelected__c value on the test Opportunity Line Item?

5) Also, we are not using the Standard Pricebook. Is there a way to get our custom pricebook in the test class code without using the SeeAllData = true option?

Answer (score 5):

> How do I setup a new test value into the Global Value set and add the same into the ProductSelected__c picklist?

You don't. You can't modify metadata of any type in a unit test.

> Also, we are not using the Standard Pricebook. Is there a way to get our custom pricebook in the test class code without using the SeeAllData = true option?

You don't. The typical method would be to create a new test price book. You can insert a standard price with `Test.getStandardPriceBookId()`, then insert custom prices with a test price book you create during the unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, in this case, do I need to pickup the value from the Global value set (It is a list of product names) and add that to the opportunity line item and also the ProductSelected__c picklist field?

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Your wording is confusing? You simply need to set the value of the field to the desired value for the unit test.

Comment: I get that. In this case, the ProductSelected__c field needs to be part of an active product in the system. So, do I need to hardcode the product name? I am trying to see if there is a way to avoid using SeeAllData = true option.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli So.... you should be using a lookup field? I think your original solution may be a bit flawed.

Comment: No, our business process is like that. There is another dependent picklist field based on the ProductSelected__c field. I just found that the trigger on the opportunity product is auto populating the ProductSelected__c field from the Product name. So, I don't need to do that in the test class. However, I still need to select an existing product from the system that is already defined as an active value on the ProductSelected__c field and use that on the Opportunity Line Item.